# How do I know when a map is loaded by GMap.NET?

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I use C# to download and save in cache some maps from OpenStreetMaps.
Problem it that I do not know when map is loaded ( downloaded from WEB)

```
using GMap.NET;
using GMap.NET.MapProviders;

GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
map.CacheLocation = @"maps";

map.Zoom = zoom;
map.Position = new PointLatLng(lat, lng);
```

That is how I set position on map. I do not know when that map is loaded from server to be sure that later it will be available from Cache when I use OnlyCache.

Comment: I had to google GMap.Net so here is a reference link for it: https://github.com/judero01col/GMap.NET But do you use it on WinForms? Isn't there a loaded event of the control?

Answer (score 1):

I down loaded GMAP.NET source code which has sample code.  Found they are using events

```
          MainMap.OnMapTypeChanged += new MapTypeChanged(MainMap_OnMapTypeChanged);
          MainMap.OnMapZoomChanged += new MapZoomChanged(MainMap_OnMapZoomChanged);
          MainMap.OnPositionChanged += new PositionChanged(MainMap_OnPositionChanged);
```

Comment: Yes, I use it in WinForms.
In my program I set position and zoom, and after that map region is being downloaded. I want to know when that region download finishes.

Comment: The only way you know when it finishes using Async is when you get to the event.  So you need to block until the event fires.  So I normally use a WaitOne (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=netframework-4.7.2).  A good example of using the Waitone is shown in the Socket Async Example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example)